# Pandas group-by and sum/storing

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to store the result of a groupby sum query in a variable  so I can use it in plotting later but Python keeps through an error message everytime i try to access it. any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share a part of the dataframe you're using?

Comment: Instead of calling stage2.index(), try just stage2

Comment: It should be `stage2.index`

Comment: index is not a function, you can try: `stage2.index`

Comment: Please do not post code and output/errors in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum is already stored in the stage2 dataframe. Instead of calling stage2.index() in your code, try running just stage2.

```
stage1 = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2019], 'Incidents': [1,2,3,4,5]})
stage2 = stage1.groupby(['Year']).sum()
print(stage2)
```

Output:

```
      Incidents
Year           
2018          1
2019          7
2020          3
2021          4
```